# PgAdmin 4 Backup User

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am trying to make a user in PgAdmin 4 for my postgresql server that will be able to create backups of databases but will not be able to read any of the data in the databases. I was able to accomplish this on my MS SQL Server but it seams that no matter what I do on postgresql, if the user doesn't have read privileges then they cannot create backups. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: How to backup if you cannot read it?

Comment: @dwir182 What I mean is that they should be able to create a full backup but not be able to run say a select statement.